# Pivot and left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, left-join

T-SQL, need help with combining 2 values in an column when Pivoting.

I have a Employee table with the below data -

```
EmpId   Status  L#
E1      A       1
E1      B       1
E2      A       2
E2      B       2
E3      B       3
E3      C       3
E3      D       3
```

and a Supervisor Table -

```
EmpId   Sup
E1      S1
E2      S2
E3      S3
```

I would like to combine the values for L# when the Status is B or C

```
EmpId   Sup   A   B,C   D
E1      S1    1   1     0
E2      S2    1   2     0
E3      S3    0   2     1
```

Comment: Your expected output shows _five_ columns but only has _four_ column headers.  Please fix your data.

Comment: which database you used? oracle or sqlserver

Comment: Thanks Tim. The headers are off. I left joined the Employee Table with Supervisor table. So 4 columns from Employee table and 1 column (Sup) from Supervisor table.

Comment: @Ajay2707, SQLserver

Comment: @JHegde In your expected result, how is the value for E2->S2->A is `1` shouldn't it be `2`, if you're taking count then the value for E2->S2->B,C should be `1` not `2`. Please clarify

Comment: @MJoy, my apologies, yes it should be 1 for E2->S2->B,C since its a count not sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation.  I am a little unclear what the results are.  The following counts the statuses:

```
select s.empid, s.sup,
       sum(case when status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as a,
       sum(case when status in ('B', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) as bc,
       sum(case when status = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as d
from employee e join
     supervisor s
     on e.empid = s.empid
group by s.empid, s.sup;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
DECLARE @TableEmp TABLE (EmpId VARCHAR(10),   Status VARCHAR(10),  L# INT)
INSERT INTO @TableEmp VALUES
('E1',  'A',   1    ),
('E1',  'B',   1    ),
('E2',  'A',   2    ),
('E2',  'B',   2    ),
('E3',  'B',   3    ),
('E3',  'C',   3    ),
('E3',  'D',   3    )


DECLARE @TableSup TABLE(EmpId VARCHAR(10),  Sup VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TableSup VALUES
('E1',  'S1'),
('E2',  'S2'),
('E3',  'S3')

SELECT EmpId, Sup ,ISNULL(A,0) A, ISNULL(B,0) B,ISNULL(C,0) C,ISNULL(D,0) D
FROM(
    SELECT e.EmpId, Sup,Status,ISNULL(L#,0) L#
    FROM @TableEmp e
    LEFT JOIN @TableSup s ON e.EmpId = s.EmpId
) p
PIVOT(
  SUM(L#)
  FOR Status IN (A, B, C,D)
) piv
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #emp (EmpID VARCHAR(10), [Status] VARCHAR(10), L# INT)
CREATE TABLE #sup (EmpID VARCHAR(10), [Sup] VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #emp VALUES
('E1','A',0),
('E1','B',1), 
('E2','A',2),
('E2','B',2),
('E3','B',3),
('E3','C',5),
('E3','D',5)
INSERT INTO #sup VALUES
('E1','S1'),
('E2','S2'),
('E3','S3')

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT e.EmpID, s.Sup, t.[Status], COUNT(L#) AS [Cnt]
FROM #emp e
INNER JOIN #sup s ON e.EmpID = s.EmpID
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN e.[Status] IN ('B','C') THEN 'B,C' ELSE e.[Status] END)) AS T([Status])
GROUP BY e.EmpID, s.Sup, t.[Status] ) A
PIVOT (MAX([Cnt]) FOR [Status] IN ([A],[B,C],[D])) pvt
```

The result is as below,

```
EmpID   Sup   A     B,C   D
E1      S1    1     1     NULL
E2      S2    1     1     NULL
E3      S3    NULL  2     1
```